# matcher.end() выдает значение 0 при наличии еще не выведенных совпадений РВ. Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Продолжаю разбираться с регулярными выражениями, написал не большой код для парсинга html кода, есть несколько проблем:

1. При первом выводе значения группы 4 выходит значение null, причину такого вывода не нашел, возможно проблема в самом  РВ.
2. При работе цикла на пред последнем выводе строки teglwork значение matcher.end(1) становиться равным 0, из-за чего возникает ошибка, но так как под РВ подходит еще одна строка такого не должно случаться, не могу найти причину почему последняя строка не подходит под РВ. P.S. выводит только 8 из 9 совпадений которые имеются в String html.

Вот сам код:

```
boolean term = false;
int count = 1;
do{
    term = false;
    String regexplwork = "(<DL>)<DT><li>(.+)|(.*)<A HREF=.+><b>(.+)</b></A> &nbsp; <b>.+k</b> &nbsp;";//загружаем условия поиска
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regexplwork);
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(html); //производим поиск по условию
    String teglwork = ""; 
    if (matcher1.find(count)) {
        teglwork = matcher1.group(4); //записываем в переменную необходимое значение группы 4
        term = matcher1.find(); // условие работы цикла, вероятно это не правильное условие, но т.к. цикл до конца не может доработать, проверить не могу.
        if (matcher1.end(1) != 0){
            count = matcher1.end(1);// записываю последний индекс найденного совпадения, что бы начать поиск новых совпадений с него.
        }
    }
 System.out.println(teglwork + " " + matcher1.find(count) +  " count=" + count);// а теперь получаем вывод необходимых данных.
 }while(term);
```

В переменной html храниться следующая строка:

```
<dl>

<!-------- вместо <body> вставятся ссылки на произведения! ------>

</small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr1><a href=index_1.shtml><font color=#393939>Дороги сказок</font></a>[2]</b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>Долгие дороги сказок - все книги в одном файле.</i></font></p>

</small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr2><a href=index_2.shtml><font color=#393939>Творчество читателей</font></a>[2]</b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>Здесь  размещается творчество читателей по моим "Сказкам", за что им огромное СПАСИБО! Доступ открыт для всех</i></font></p>

</small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr3><a href=index_3.shtml><font color=#393939>Записки морфа.</font></a>[2]</b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>Фантастика, чтиво без намеков на научность, ни на что не претендую, просто взгляд на вымышленный мир недалёкого будущего.Мир разменял третий десяток двадцать первого века. Россия стоит на пороге широкомасштабной войны, но случилось чудо. На орбите старушки Земли появилась инопланетная станция. создание чужого разума принялось "поливать"  поверхность неизвестным излучением, вызвав  тем самым миллионы жертв и навсегда изменив политическую карту  мира. В России произошёл военный переворот,коренным образом изменивший одну шестую часть суши. вскоре  появились первые последствия от излучения инопланетной бандуры - у людей начал изменяться код ДНК. Для чего это нужно станции и инопланетному разуму, чем это грозит землянам?ВНИМАНИЕ! ТЕКСТ СЕКВЕСТИРОВАН по требованию издательства. Договор ушёл в ЛенИздат.</i></font></p>

</small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr5>Столкновение:<gr0></b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>Наш мир не единственный. Вселенная многогранна, Большой взрыв  репродуцировал множество параллельных миров. миров  технологических и магических, границу между которыми прочертило время, а так ли сильно отличаются миры и может ли магия проникнуть в наш мир? Что будет, если это произойдёт? а может наш мир когда-то сталкивался с магией?</i></font></p>
<DL><DT><li><A HREF=st.shtml><b>Столкновение. Часть 1.</b></A> &nbsp; <b>1145k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>5.90*171</b> &nbsp;  Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/st">Комментарии: 668 (12/11/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Общая сборка после правки ошибок. Низкий поклон моим  добровольным бетам. Спасибо Виталий Н, Наталия, Андрей  и  Иван за Ваш труд и помощь. Отдельный поклон Семарглу за помощь в восстановлении утерянного отрывка.  Первая книга полностью.   Книга отправлена в издательство. Надеюсь на скорый выход в бумаге.</font><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/st/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 5 шт.</a></small></DL>
<DL><DT><li><font color=red size=-2>Upd</font><A HREF=st6.shtml><b>Столкновение. 2 - я книга.</b></A> &nbsp; <b>528k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>6.45*370</b> &nbsp;  Фантастика, Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/st6">Комментарии: 28 (14/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Сводный файл на 13 декабря. Продолжаю накидывать текст.  Жду ваших дельных советов и предложений по правкам крайнего содержимого. Спасибо за Ваши комментарии, уважаемые читатели, отдельный низкий поклон Ивану. По мотивам комментов 866, 867 и 876 в текст будут внесены правки - спасибо! По-прежнему принимаются замечания, советы, тапки, табуретки, а также аргументированная критика. Заявления: "Всё га**о" и "автор убейся ап стену", не рассматриваются. На неделе постараюсь обновиться ещё пару раз. С уважением, Александр Сапегин.</font><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/st6/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 4 шт.</a></small></DL>
<DL><DT><li><font color=red size=-2>Upd</font><A HREF=st7.shtml><b>Столкновение. 2 - я книга. Прода.</b></A> &nbsp; <b>25k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>8.02*169</b> &nbsp;  Фантастика, Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/st7">Комментарии: 338 (16/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Прода от 13 декабря, добавил чуть-чуть. Жду ваших дельных советов и предложений по правкам крайнего содержимого. Спасибо за Ваши комментарии, уважаемые читатели. Планируемый сюжет про Храм не завершён.С уважением, Александр Сапегин.</font><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/st7/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 1 шт.</a></small></DL>

</small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr6>Фанфики по ГП: :<gr0></b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>"Жизнь на лезвии бритвы". Автор - папа Евгении Сапегиной. Долгожданный доченькой фик.</i></font></p>
<DL><DT><li><font color=gray size=-2>Upd</font><A HREF=gp.shtml><b>Жизнь на лезвии бритвы.</b></A> &nbsp; <b>1003k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>6.35*389</b> &nbsp;  Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/gp">Комментарии: 164 (10/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Фанфик на Гарри Поттера. Пишется по просьбе любимой доченьки. Размер: миди-макси Пейринг: ГП/ГГ, ГП/ГД Рейтинг: РГ-13 Попаданцы - наше всё! Попаданец в ГП. МС, но сил на него положится много, бесплатных плюшек не будет. Избранный - не избранный, вся слава младшему братцу. Дамбигад (тот ещё гад), Снейпогад, Уизли идут лесом. Нормальные адекватные Дурсли. Джеймс Поттер жив. У ГП есть брат - Джейс. Сириус не сиделец Азкабана.</font></DL>
<DL><DT><li><font color=gray size=-2>Upd</font><A HREF=gp1.shtml><b>Жизнь на лезвии бритвы. Прода.</b></A> &nbsp; <b>0k</b> &nbsp; <small> Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/gp1">Комментарии: 210 (28/11/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Сюжет и 1-я часть книги завершены. далее лето и второй курс.</font><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/gp1/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 6 шт.</a></small></DL>
<DL><DT><li><font color=brown size=-2>New</font><A HREF=gp2.shtml><b>Жизнь на лезвии бритвы. Книга вторая.</b></A> &nbsp; <b>63k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>8.61*140</b> &nbsp;  Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/gp2">Комментарии: 111 (14/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Прода от 06 декабря. Лето, будни, каникулы, почти ничего не происходит...</font></DL>

 </small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr7>Питомец:<gr0></b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>Повесть о необычном попаданце</i></font></p>
<DL><DT><li><A HREF=pitomec.shtml><b>Питомец</b></A> &nbsp; <b>275k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>6.47*222</b> &nbsp;  Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/pitomec">Комментарии: 433 (07/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/pitomec/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 8 шт.</a></small></DL>
<DL><DT><li><A HREF=pitomec-1.shtml><b>Питомец. прода</b></A> &nbsp; <b>50k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>6.74*139</b> &nbsp;  Фэнтези  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/pitomec-1">Комментарии: 499 (03/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">Здравствуйте, уважаемые читатели! выкладка от 16 ноября. Данный раздел будет предназначен для прод и правки текста. Проды  выкладываются частями и в основной текст не добавляются. Выкладывается новая, удаляется старая, и так до самого конца. Таким образом будет соблюдена коммерциализация проекта и возможные интересы Издательства. Пока загадывать рано, всё вилами по воде писано, но, возможно, "Питомец" поселится на бумаге.     ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ ДЛЯ ЧИТАТЕЛЕЙ! Третья попытка кардинально переписать окончание романа с треском провалилась. Автора ожидаемо понесло в дебри и в сторону, слишком много веток для возможных ответвлений оказалось заложено в книге, вот и пошёл я разрабатывать Южный континент и драконов, живущих там. Написал, почитал, что получилось и снёс, так как главный герой постепенно потерялся в сутолоке событий (есть за мной такая слабость и грех - "Столкновение" вам примером). Самая первая версия романа никак не хочет умирать, всеми своими килобайтами текста цепляясь за жизнь и отстаивая право считаться каноном. пусть так, смиряюсь, оставляя за собой право внести в него правки и включить в него малую часть наработок и повествований из мертворождённых переделок. Чуть добавится мотивации, уберутся некоторые противоречия, плеснётся немного войны, изменится концовка и судьба главгероя и главгероини.       С уважением,  Александр Сапегин.</font><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/pitomec-1/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 5 шт.</a></small></DL>

</small><p><font size=+1><b><a name=gr8>Тоннельщики:<gr0></b></font><br>

<font color=#393939 size=-1><i>Фантастическо-производственный роман с элементами трудовых и боевых будней. Всем строителям тоннелей посвящается.(на научную ценность не претендую)</i></font></p>
<DL><DT><li><A HREF=tn.shtml><b>Тоннельщики</b></A> &nbsp; <b>132k</b> &nbsp; <small>Оценка:<b>6.46*64</b> &nbsp;  Фантастика  <A HREF="/comment/s/sapegin_a_p/tn">Комментарии: 150 (05/12/2015)</A> </small><br><DD><font color="#555555">    Маленькая прода от 15 марта 2015, прода выделена синим. Перевожу Тоннельщиков в разряд основных, думаю, проды теперь будут появляться регулярно.  Черновик, не бечено. Производственно-приключенческий роман о космических тоннельщиках 26-го века от Р.Х. Производственные будни, политика, краткая история русского сектора, звёздолёты, сражения, красавицы и злобные пираты прилагаются.</font><DD><small><a href=/img/s/sapegin_a_p/tn/index.shtml>Иллюстрации/приложения: 1 шт.</a></small>  </DL>


</dl>
```

Буду благодарен за найденные ошибки в моем коде и способы их устранения!

Comment: Самая главная ошибка - использовать регулярные выражения для анализа HTML-кода.

Comment: Спасибо, я увы не знал этого момента! Но в любом случае теперь уже надо довести код до ума, за то в дальнейшем для меня это будет хорошим пособием по РВ.

Comment: Я по моему уже в 5 вопросах написал и вам напишу. Не надо использовать регулярки для HTML! Используйте например: http://jsoup.org/

Comment: К сожалению, мне кажется, довести до ума в Java не получится. В этом языке сложные регулярные выражения очень часто приводят к ошибке переполнения стека. Нет поддержки рекурсии.

Comment: По-моему, регулярка делает не то, что вы думаете, из-за "|".

Comment: @Vartlok благодарю за ссылку, буду разбираться!

Comment: @stribizhev это к сожалению печально, в таком случае буду рассматривать другие пути реализации парсинга html. Но в любом случает, простой html код выступает не плохим учебным материалом для изучения РВ.

Comment: @zRrr вы имеете в виду 2 и 3 группу? (.+)|(.*)? Как раз это было введено специально т.к. в html коде присутствуют два регулярных выражения `"(<DL>)<DT><li>(.*)<A HREF=.+><b>(.+)</b></A> &nbsp; <b>.+k</b> &nbsp;"` и `"(<DL>)<DT><li>(.+)<A HREF=.+><b>(.+)</b></A> &nbsp; <b>.+k</b> &nbsp;"` поэтому решил сделать через `|` . Или я где то ошибся и данный символ используется не для этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на Jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse( html );
// Выбрать все теги <b>, лежащие непосредственно внутри <a>, которые где-то там входят в <li>
for ( Element element : doc.select( "li a>b" ) ) {
    System.out.println( element.text() );
}
```

Регулярка:

```
//<DL><DT><li><A HREF=st.shtml><b>Столкновение. Часть 1.</b></A>
//<DL><DT><li><font color=red size=-2>Upd</font><A HREF=st6.shtml><b>Столкновение. 2 - я книга.</b></A>
String regexplwork = "<DL><DT><li>(?:<font.+?</font>)?<A HREF=.+?><b>(.+?)</b></A>";//загружаем условия поиска
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regexplwork);
Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(html);

while (matcher1.find()) {
    System.out.println( matcher1.group(1) );
}
```

Разбор полетов:

Оператор `|` указывает, что выражение совпадает либо с тем, что слева от него, либо с тем, что справа, т.е. в вашем случае строка совпадает либо с `(<DL>)<DT><li>(.+)`, либо с `(.*)<A HREF=.+><b>(.+)</b></A> &nbsp; <b>.+k</b> &nbsp;`. Соответственно, вначале строка совпадала с левой частью, потом вы отступали на 4 знака (содержимое первой группы) и срабатывала правая часть, а в первой группе было пусто, поэтому `matcher1.end(1)` возвращал 0.

Вместо этого часть, которая бывает в строке не всегда, можно указать с квантификатором (квантором?) `?`: `(?:<font.+?</font>)?`. Конструкция `(?: )` означает незахватывающую группу, т.к. ее содержимое нам не важно.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает, отдельное спасибо за вариант на Jsoup.